# JQuery passing element by id in razor ASP.Net Core Visual Studio 2017

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio, razor

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.0 on Visual Studio 2017. I'm trying to pass an id element from the _Layout.cshtml in the Shared file to the Index.cshtml which is in the Home file, but my code isn't working.

This is my navigation bar in _Layout.

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Food and Drinks<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="update" id="restaurant" onclick="update(this)">Restaurant</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="update" id="cafe" onclick="update(this)">Cafe</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="update" id="bakery" onclick="update(this)">Bakery</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This is my buggy query in Index.cshtml. I'm testing to see if I'm getting the correct id by having `alert(type);` but it returns the value as `undefined` each time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".update").click(function update(e) {
        var type = $(e).attr('id');
        alert(type);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")',
            data: { type: type },
            success: function (result) {

                $('#form').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `e` is the event, not the element.  `this` is the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `onclick="update(this)"` as you are using unobtrusive event handler

and use current element content `this` to retrieve attribute value

```
var type = $(this).attr('id'); //this.id;
```

Also to persist arbitrary data use custom data-* attributes which can be fetched using `.data()`

```js
$(".update").click(function(e) {
  var type = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="update" data-id="restaurant">Restaurant</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="update" data-id="cafe">Cafe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="update" data-id="bakery">Bakery</a></li>
</ul>
```